How can I add use INDEX(player_custom_idx) to mysql query in quill without nesting
I can write custom query
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

def rawQuery = quote {
    sql"""Select p.name, p.age FROM Person p use INDEX(player_custom_idx)""".as[Query[Person]]
}
run(rawQuery)

Query is nested:
SELECT x.name, x.age FROM (Select p.name, p.age FROM Person p use INDEX(player_custom_idx)) x

How can I build query with index hint but without nesting in subquery?
